# Which is the better & efficient approach: parse a string to enum and compare or convert enum to string and compare?

Tags: c#, enums

Here are both the codes:

`if (Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum),data["rowName"].ToString()).Equals(SomeEnum.EnumValue))`

Or

`if (data["rowName"].ToString().Equals(SomeEnum.EnumValue.ToString()))`

Which is the better and more efficient approach?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Do you know the type of `data["rowName"]`?

Comment: As a general principle, if your language has types, you should use them. Avoid "stringly typed" values.

Comment: The datatype of the column in db is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly cast to enum. ie:

```
if ((SomeEnum)data["rowName"] == SomeEnum.EnumValue)
```

You wouldn't want to convert to string.

Note: And generally it is filtered right when pulling the data off the database.

EDIT: It is very unlikely one would be keeping enum values in the database as a string. The expected type is an integral numeric. It wouldn't cause an exception if there is (say integer) value in the database that is not in the enum values. Here is a demo using the Northwind sample database (Note that shipper Federal Express is not defined in the Enum values):

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXpress;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var reader = new SqlCommand("select * from Orders",con).ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((Shipper)reader["ShipVia"] != Shipper.SpeedyExpress)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($@"{(int)reader["OrderId"]}, {(Shipper)reader["ShipVia"]}");
            }
        }
    }

}

public enum Shipper
{
    None,
    SpeedyExpress,
    UnitedPackage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way. That way youavoid getting a `InvalidCastException` if the cast goes wrong, and can handle it gracefully or throw a custom exception.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enumAsString = "Value1";
        Enum.TryParse(enumAsString, out SomeEnum enumeration);

        if (enumeration == SomeEnum.Value1)
            Console.WriteLine("success");
    }
}

public enum SomeEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

Comment: But why would you think data["rowName"] is a string? Or convert that to a string? It is very unlikely an enum value would exist in the database as a string.